# Unable to access our angular website on Iphone?

Tags: android, iphone, angular

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WorkFridge - A Magic Box</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Unable to access our angular website on iPhone but can be accessed on the android phone. we are getting a black screen on iPhone.

website url: http://stage.workfridge.com

Comment: I managed to access through iPhone. Check again

Comment: which model? and currently for us it's not working on 4S

Comment: On my iPhone X it's working. I could imagine that the iOS on a 4S is just too old.

Comment: working on IPhone 6

Comment: You have to be careful with "old" versions of iOS Safari. For example they do not support [Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).